# *ngFor is not rendering any data into the front end (html page)

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, rendering, ngfor, angular-directive

**This is my Component code:**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-component2',
  templateUrl: './home-component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-component2.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  posts = [{title:'t1', content:'c1'},
  {title:'t2', content:'c2'},
  {title:'t3', content:'c3'}];
}
```

**This is my HTML Code **

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<h2 *ngIf="posts.length <= 0">no data addedd</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post for posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*ngFor directive is not rendering any data to the html page, It is not even showing error.
please help me out.

Comment: It is a simple typo which is viewable on your console.log in the web browser inspector tools.

Comment: Have you fix this correcting the typo in the `*ngFor` (should use 'of' instead of 'for')? If that is not the case and the problem persist please edit the question fixing the typo in order to provide you more help on this.

Answer (score 1):

it's `let post of posts` instead of `let post for posts`.

Check https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description for more info